# Wysiwyg Textarea Editor Turkish Character Display

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg

im using Summernote  WYSIWYG editor.
(https://github.com/summernote/summernote)

I want to set the content of textarea manually. I use these codes as explained on documentations:

```
var markupStr = 'İÇERİKĞÖLŞ';
$('#summernote').summernote('code', markupStr);
```

But some special characters (like ç, ş, i, ğ ... ) displays as '�'. How can we display them correctly.

Comment: Did you try adding  <meta charset="UTF-8"> in you html <head>?

Comment: Yes, Turkish characters display correctly on page, but when i set a text including Turkish characters in textarea it displays like �

Comment: Try including Turkish language.   <script type="text/javascript" src="../lang/summernote-tr-TR.js"></script>Then initiate it with $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.summernote').summernote({
        height: 200,
        tabsize: 2,
        lang: 'tr-TR'
      });
    }); like in this example https://github.com/summernote/summernote/blob/develop/examples/lang.html

Comment: Languages can be found here: https://github.com/summernote/summernote/tree/develop/lang

Comment: I've included summernote-tr-TR.js, but it just translates button's explanations to Turkish. Not about Turkish characters :(

Comment: It also adds relevant fonts. I think it's a font problem. Try playing with it.

Comment: Ok. <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-9"> solved the problem....

Answer (score -1):

When u displaying content, use that

> {!! utf8_decode(html_entity_decode($content)) !!}

It works for me.